# Customize notifications on Android wear (watch)

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm developing an app on Android which send notifications connected to an Android watch (emulator).
I can display the notifications on the watch all is ok but I would like to customize these notifications on the watch. I already used the WearableExtender object but you only can change the background and hide the logo and that's not enough. I would like to create my own layouts.

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to further customize the "peek" that initially appears, but you can build a completely custom screen for the full notification. See Google's [Custom Layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you ! I tested this tutorial http://www.doubleencore.com/2014/07/create-custom-ongoing-notification-android-wear/. It works but it's not very simple.